# How to color specific cells if another cell contains a string in Excel?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to change the fill and font color of only A2 and B2 if E2 contains the string "departments" for example.

I have found formulas that highlight the whole row, but I only want select cells of the row while actually formatting with colors, and I can't quite get it right with conditional formatting.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please describe the formula you used and the range to which you applied it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a rule based on the following formula:

```
=SEARCH("departments",$E1)>0
```

and apply it to columns A and B.

[image]

<sub>You can also simplify the formula to just `=SEARCH("departments",$E1)`</sub>